# What is BB(n) terminology precisely saying about symbols, states, space, and steps involved?

Tags: terminology, busy-beaver

This question is mainly about the clarification of the terminology `BB(n)`, not how busy beavers work. It seems common to refer to busy beaver numbers like `BB(2)` assuming `2` is the number of states. Do we also assume `2` input symbols? Further, is the result of `BB(2)` referring to the count of ones printed or the count of steps?

Simply put, what is `BB(2)`? 6, 4, BB(2,m), a bound, etc?

Comment: This is answered in papers and websites on the problem. Have you looked for any?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus oh yes -- I've seen n-state/1-symbol/2-symbol, m=n symbol... seems to be some noise. I think Wikipedia had n-state/2-symbol.

Comment: There might be more than one common definition, or to state it differently, it is the concept that matters rather than the details.